# Looking through text file for specific string

Tags: python-2.7

For my question I already have a solution but for the sake of my personal improvement I want to know a much better to solve the same problem.

From a course, as part of a quiz we were to look for lines in a text starting with :

> From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008

and to extract the email string from the text, but first we were to use split() when we found the matches. The sample output should be this :

```
louis@media.berkeley.edu
louis@media.berkeley.edu
ray@media.berkeley.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
There were 27 lines in the file with From as the first word
```

This is the code I came up that worked for the assignment. I am open to suggestions of better ways to have written my program to extract the email string

```
import re

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
count = 0
matches = []

for lines in fh :
    # look for specific characters in document text
    if not lines.startswith("From ") : continue
    # increment the count variable for each math found
    count += 1
    # append the required lines to the matches list
    matches.append(lines)
    # loop through the list to acess each line individually
    for email in matches :
        # place values in variable
        out = email
        # looking through each line for any email add found
        found = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', out)
        # loop through the found emails and print them out
        for i in found :
            ans = i
    print ans       
    # print count
print "There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if your code works, and it's real (not example) code, it probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I got flamed for recommending CodeReview two days ago, so be sure and check their site rules for on-topicness if you plan to post there. That said, questions where the code works but you want it to be written better are generally **off-topic** at StackOverflow. Your question **may** be a better fit there.

Comment: okay. Thanks i'll do that